# Execute query after all conditions

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I used EF in my .NET 6 Project.
I want to do some condition then run query.
For Ex:

```
 var ProductModelList = Product.Include(b => b.Brand);
if (BrandId > 0)
 {
  ProductModelList.Where(b => b.BrandId == BrandId);
 }
 ProductModelList.Skip(skip).Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

Is this true way?
Thank u to help

Comment: would be better to just do the query, check the variable in outside this function. but this all has to do with what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is right way, but your code has issue:
`IQueryable` is immutable and you have to assign new query to variable.

```cs
var query = Product.Include(b => b.Brand).AsQueryable();
if (BrandId > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.BrandId == BrandId);
}
var ProductModelList = query.Skip(skip).Take(PageSize).ToList();
```